# I am unable to play an MP3 file using Mediaplayer class in Android

Tags: java, android

As you can see in the  image it does not recognizes the start() method:
[image: As you can see in the image it does not recognizes the start() method]

http://prntscr.com/jv12wq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must type the code inside the "onCreate" Methode Example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.p);
    mediaPlayer.start();
 }
```

Comment: Yes got the idea Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You call `play.start()` outside a method. This isn't allowed in Java.

Put `play.start()` inside a method (like `onCreate`)

And, as mentioned by Gabe Sechan in a comment, creating the MediaPlayer requires a context. You supply `this`, which means the initialization of the MediaPlayer needs to go into onCreate as well..

Comment: Also, he's using a context in the call to create the MediaPlayer before its initialized.  That's also invalid.  All of that code needs to go inside onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the job of creating and starting the media player in the onCreate() method after the content view has been set.